# Memory leaking thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have a TabHost with TextViews associated to each tab, in an Activity context. Currently there's also an AsyncTask which manages the TCP socket and when it receives some kind of information, it's sent to the main Activity handler, who calls a method to append the text to the current TextView.

Well, after a while (approx 5 minutes) of running, I notice how it starts hanging and finally I get an ANR. So I installed Memory Analyzer for Eclipse and in conjunction with DDMS, I was able to find out what seems to be the bottleneck, but not how to deal with it.

Using the previously mentioned tools, I was able to see hundreds of lines like the ones on this pic:

[image]

**BTW**: There's a strange detail in that pic, the Thread Id is always 1; shouldn't it be different for each thread as the append is called on different threads?

Those hundreds of lines reference to the two 'appends' you may see in the code above. I'm new to the thread world, so if you see something weird, I'd appreciate any advice. This is the code where the bottleneck is:

```
// tab = is the name of the tab where to append the new text
// line = the line to append; it may contain spans, colors, bold text, etc... that's why it's a SpannableStringBuilder
// ColorLine is a method that just returns a SpannableStringBuilder-formatted string

synchronized private static void Write2Tab(final String tab, final SpannableStringBuilder line) {
  final TabHost lth = (TabHost) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  final TextView tabContent = (TextView) lth.getCurrentView();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      String curtab = getCurrentTabName();

      // If the current tab is the one where we need to write, we do
      if (tab.equalsIgnoreCase(curtab)) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            tabContent.append(linea);
            tabContent.append((ColorLine("\n", Color.WHITE, false, 0, 1)));
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }).start();

  [...]
}
```

I've had 2 more memory leaks in my code that I was able to fix, but this one's starting to be a bit hard... Any ideas of why is this happening and how to fix it?

**--------------- EDIT ---------------**

After several days of frustrating research about leaks in my app, I found out there was more than one. I managed to solve them, the one I originally posted had to do with John Vint's post, there was an issue with the buffering control which made a substancial accumulation of SpannableStringBuilder objects in the TextView, so I'm accepting his post. Now I have a different issue with another curious leak but it has nothing to do with the original post so I'm going to open a new question.

Comment: Where do you call Write2Tab?

Comment: As far I know memory leak in Java is not possible. All the memory you are occuping is under your control, otherwise, garbage collector would free it.

Comment: @HAL9000 If you keep allocating memory, your application will be slow due the work of the garbagecollector.

Comment: I suggest you to read about garbage-collecting and weakreferences at wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference

Comment: @RobinDijkhof This method is called from the same Activity where Write2Tab is called. The AsyncTask gets the line from the socket, sends it via the Handler to the MainActivity and there's where Write2Tab is called.

Comment: I tried what @user2365568 proposed as I have never worked with Weak References, but in this case it didn't help. Declaring the SpannableStrings as WeakReferences entails that there's a gap between the object declaration and the object appending where it can be freed by the Garbage Collector, and that's what happens. And I can't afford losing even one of those messages. But thanks for the reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large does the StringBuilder become?

If the thread is stuck at 253 like it shows in your heap dumb all I can think of is that you are running out of heap space and are getting a GC overhead limit reached.

If that's the case you will need buffer the StringBuilder (ie if the length > N than remove the oldest line, where N is a large enough number to have history but small enough to prevent OOM).

Comment: I'm actually doing this, each tab has a 30-line limit. If it surpass this limit, the oldest current_lines - 30 are erased. That was another of the leaks, but I was able to fix it.

Comment: @user3001496 Ok. Unfortunately there isn't enough information.  It appears that everything should be lined up for allocation when needed.

Comment: Note the ThreadId: 1 may just mean the UI thread.  When you say `runOnUiThread` it is placing the task on a queue and will run it later.